# Google Test - Test that a string does not contain a string

Tags: regex, googletest, googlemock

Using Google Test, I need a way to verify that a string that was returned by my class under test does not contain a particular string. I can currently test that a string does contain another string by using EXPECT_THAT and MatchesRegex; however, I don't know how to build a valid POSIX Extended regular expression for not containing a word, and I don't know how to negate a MatchesRegex call.

I tried doing a regex I found here on SO:

```
EXPECT_THAT(returnedString, MatchesRegex("^(?!.*badword).*$"));
```

but that gives me an error:

```
Regular expression "^(?!.*badword).*$" is not a valid POSIX Extended regular expression.
```

Any other suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can combine matchers `HasSubstr` and `Not` so your code would look like:

```
EXPECT_THAT(returnedString, Not(HasSubstr("badword")));
```

Check Google Mock [documentation for matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md) for full reference.

Comment: It seems we also need `using ::testing::HasSubstr;` for this to work.  Thanks

Comment: Updated link:  https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#matchers-matcherlist